# Overload UserManager.SendEmailAsync method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I right click to look for the implementation of `UserManager.SendEmailAsync`, it takes me to, which I assume, the Metafile Class which contains the following method:

`public virtual async Task SendEmailAsync(TKey userId, string subject, string body)`

Due to some special circumstances, I would like to overload(not override) the method so that `SendEmailAsync` will take either `userId` OR `string email` directly.

I don't suppose I can make changes in the Metafile. I'm wondering if it is possible to overload this method? If not, what is my alternative?

Comment: What if userId is string? You won't be able to differentiate the methods then.

Comment: I thought of that too, my initial idea is to "cheat" the way through, i.e. The method that will take the `string email` will have 4 parameters (with the last parameter act as a dummy)

Comment: Ugh, why on earth would you do that? That's an awful practice. Why not just create `SendEmailByEmailAsync`?

Comment: Then I will have 2 almost duplicated set of Email Services codes, which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: What would be duplicate exactly?